# How reduce the growth of a database in SQL Server CE?

Tags: database, size, sql-server-ce

I have a database with 468 MB.

I deleted all tables and the size of this database is the same.

Why size of this database is the same?

Comment: Because your implied assumption that deleting data would reduce the file size is false. For performance reasons, this is not done - unless you specifically ask for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `Shrink` or `Compact` the database to reclaim the empty space in the database file.

See this blog post: [SqlCeEngine/ISSCEEngine: Shrink Vs Compact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2007/10/26/sqlceengine-issceengine-shrink-vs-repair.aspx)